# Define constants on a Scanner

Tags: java

I'm starting learn Java and I'm studying constants right now. I'm able to do a Scanner in a constant?

For example:

```
public static final double dolarInReal;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
dolarInReal = sc.nextDouble();
```

This is just an example for you to understand what I'm supposed to do. Is it possible?

Comment: Try compiling that code and see what happens.

Comment: Technically this wouldn't be a constant (formally, only a subset of `static final` fields are real constants in Java). But doing this looks like a bad idea to me. In any case, given `sc` is not static, nor is `dolarInReal = sc.nextDouble();` in a static initializer, this won't compile.

Comment: Just for your inform any attribute defined as `static` and `final` is considered to be a perfect constant and the standard is to name it all in upper case and each word separated by an underscore. So, dolarInReal can be renamed as DOLAR_IN_REAL.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Formally only `static final` fields initialized with a constant expression are real constants (but granted, informally, all static final fields are considered constants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided has a couple of issues:

1. Declaration without initialization: When you declare a public static final double dolarInReal; as a static final field, you must initialize it at the point of declaration or in a static initialization block. However, you are trying to initialize it later in your code with dolarInReal = sc.nextDouble();. This is not allowed for a final field.
2. You are trying to read a double from the Scanner after declaring a final variable, which is not allowed. Final variables must be initialized when declared and cannot be modified afterwards.

To fix this, you can initialize dolarInReal when declaring it or initialize it in a static block:

```
public static final double dolarInReal;
static {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   dolarInReal = sc.nextDouble();
}
```